# AWS Lambda C# EF Core Serialization Error

Tags: aws-lambda, c#-6.0, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I created a .net 6 minimal API project with EF Core that uses DI to create repositories with Scoped lifetime.  The API project uses mediatr to send the request to a proper handler.  The handler's get injected with db repositories.  This works when I run this project directly.

I am migrating that project to an AWS Lambda project using the new AWS .NET 6 Templates in the visual studio toolkit.  For whatever reason, the exact same code that runs fine in the minimal API project now throws an error because the injected repositories dispose their connections before the end of the request.

This error occurs anytime I run a command against the database.

I believe this is happening because of a serialization error that occurs in entity framework core.  This issue doesn't occur in my regular project because I'm guessing it's using a different serializer to handle the serialization of entities.

The errors being thrown are:

1. System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.
2. Cannot access a disposed context instance

If I update the Json Serializer that .net is using to handle cycles, then the 1st error turns into: "System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Type' instances are not supported".

This looks like some sort of conflict with Pomelo Entity Framework Core
and the way the .net 6 lambda templated project is setup.

EDIT:
After looking at this more, I think the issue is with whatever serialization library that AWS Lambda template project uses vs whatever serialization library is normally used by Pomelo to handle things.

Comment: Pomelo does not use any serialization library. This is very likely to be an issue unrelated to Pomelo or EF Core. It looks like you are getting an exception from somewhere and some of your ASP.NET Core components wants to return it to the caller as JSON, which then hits this serialization exception. It is also possible, that whatever you are returning is just too deep for the default JSON settings in which case the exception you get is expected. I believe we are handling your issue on our repo under https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1604.